# Couldn't connect to host server (odoo v11)

Tags: postgresql, ip, host, odoo-11

I was working on odoo, precisely in Website builder module while I was creating a website via the host IP address 192.168.1.2:9012, suddenly it crashes and shown me an Internal server error.
I tried to have a look at the log file and got this traceback,

```
    2018-12-06 18:14:31,432 1 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
    2018-12-06 18:14:31,436 1 INFO ? werkzeug: 192.168.1.9 - - [06/Dec/2018 18:14:31] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    2018-12-06 18:14:31,441 1 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 205, in run_wsgi
        execute(self.server.app)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in execute
        application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 250, in app
        return self.app(e, s)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 166, in application
        return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 154, in application_unproxied
        result = handler(environ, start_response)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1318, in _call_
        return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1292, in _call_
        return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in _call_
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1455, in dispatch
        self.setup_db(httprequest)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1387, in setup_db
        httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1539, in db_monodb
        dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1506, in db_list
        dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/db.py", line 369, in list_dbs
        with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 634, in cursor
        return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 178, in _init_
        self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 517, in _locked
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 585, in borrow
        **connection_info)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
    psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No route to host
        Is the server running on host "172.17.0.4" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432 ?
```

I believe that's a network problem, I couldn't connect to the host server. do you have any idea about this please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from Odoo server because it cannot connect to the PostgreSQL database. First make sure your database service is running and available.

From your ip addresses I assume you are running database locally in some kind of virtualization environment like Docker. If you are not able to connect, please describe your environment in more detail. This will make it possible for stackoverflowers to help you.